# Android - Sending data through a socket while having getInputStream() already called

Tags: android, sockets

I am making a kind of messaging app for Android, and the data exchanging is done through sockets. So I am having the following problem.

Accepting data from the server is done well, individually. So is sending data. However, while making progress I created a service constantly awaiting for new data from the server by running a `socketObject.getInputStream()` function in a loop. If I try to send data through the socket from the client to the server, the thread sending the data is blocked, here the sending is initiated through a button press and is executed in the following code:

```
PrintWriter printwriter;
        try {
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(message);
            printwriter.flush();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I take care of it and make sure no `socketObject.getInputStream()` is being called when I send data, there is no problem.

So, what should I do? If there's something wrong with my approach, then enlighten me on what I should do. If that's the way things are, I would like to know if there is a way to stop the `getInputStream()` function from waiting for data, so I can get my sending code to work on its turn,without terminating the socket.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're stepping is the way you handle your data receiving and data sending. Long story short, in order to receive messages you need to wait in a loop (as you are already doing) using the `getInputStream()` of the socket. In order to send messages you need to work with the `getOutputStream()` which can(or maybe should) be done by the UI thread.

I'll give you this good [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) so you can have an idea of what I'm talking about (no necessarily copy/paste)

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new `PrintWriter` per message. Create it once for the life of the socket. Then you don't have to call `getOutputStream()` here at all. Similarly whatever stream/reader you're using to read input, create it once, then you don't have to call `getInputStream()` in the read loop.